# Find Two End Points Of Arc

Tags: ios

Hello I am drawing Arc with some start angle and end angle.

Here it is : `CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, p1.x, p1.y, radius, M_PI_4 - M_PI, 3 * M_PI_4 - M_PI, NO);`

Assume that center is (0,0)and radius is 20.

So what will be equation to find two end points?

Please help me.Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738605/how-to-get-points-of-arc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending point of the arc becomes the new current point of the path, so you only have to keep a pointer the last point before you add the arc for the first point and after adding - a second one for the second point.

`CGPathGetCurrentPoint()` is the function that returns the current (last) point on a path or `CGPointZero` if the path is empty.

Example code:

```
CGPoint firstPoint = CGPointZero;
CGPoint secondPoint = CGPointZero;

// get first point (last one on path just before drawing the arc)
firstPoint = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(path);

// add arc to path
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, p1.x, p1.y, radius, M_PI_4 - M_PI, 3 * M_PI_4 - M_PI, NO);

// get second point (end of arc)
secondPoint = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(path);
```